# Best Practices or Convention for File Structure for API Client

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm new to Laravel and need to write a client for an API that my application will be consuming.

I've found many posts about instantiating a Guzzle client in a controller action. It seems to me that I should write a class that consumes the API and then use that class in a controller action which will load the results into my database. It seems likely to me that it will be somewhere under the `app/Http/` directory. `Clients` perhaps?

So `app/Http/Clients/Api.php` would look like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Clients;

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ApiClient extends Client
{
}
```

The resulting controller action will be scheduled with `cron`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Services namespace, like this:

```
namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class MyApiWrapper
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_url' => 'https://your-api-domain.com'
        ]);
    }

    public function getComments($postId)
    {
        $uri = sprintf("/posts/{$postId}/comments");

        $response = $this->client->request('GET', $uri);

        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, you can do this:

```
use App\Services\MyApiWrapper;

class SomeController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $comments = (new MyApiWrapper)->getComments($postId = 123);
        return $comments;
    }
}
```

And this will return something like this:

```
[
    [
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 987,
        "post_id": 123,
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
    ],
    [
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 876,
        "post_id": 123,
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
    ],
    [
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 765,
        "post_id": 123,
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
    ]
]
```

Comment: Again, forgive me for being a Laravel n00b, but it seems that my class is not a service, but a client.

Comment: Yup. Don't worry about this. Another option is put in a `Repositories` namespace.